# Fitting distributions in R and Matlab give very different results

Tags: r, matlab, data-fitting

I am fitting a wave height dataset (m) to a generalized pareto distribution. I already selected a threshold at 0.15m. I'm transitioning from Matlab to R so I wanted to compare the results from both programs. I knew that both programs wouldn't provide the same exact answer but I was expecting to get results somewhat close to each other.

Of course, for both fittings, I used the same data and the same threshold. Both methods estimate the parameters by MLE. In Matlab, the fitdist function does not estimate the threshold. It is assumed to be known (which in this case is 0.15m), and subtracted from data before calling it (which I already did). While in R the threshold is part of the input.

The functions I used are:
Matlab:
`fitdist(data_above_threshold,'Generalized Pareto')`
R:
`fevd(data,threshold =0.15,type = 'GP',method = "MLE")`. (extRemes Package)

In Matlab I get:
`Shape:-1.0301 Scale:0.7534`  while in R I get `Shape:-0.5848505 Scale:0.3620191`

Here I attach the data so you can see the results for yourselves:

```
c(0.194101337780203, 0.289791483274648, 0.313940773547535, 0.184577674010614, 
0.102266008573448, 0.045464156804826, 0.0486387113946889, 0.143761972140945, 
0.267342847246331, 0.242966803074167, 0.069386693178437, 0.0099771715681416, 
0.00736950172646855, 0.056121590070795, 0.0759625562574393, 0.145009118586962, 
0.258045937376017, 0.379926158236833, 0.236844447793717, 0.0861664817248564, 
0.0503393656392586, 0.156233436601121, 0.118138781522764, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
0.0442170103588082, 4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 0.0143988726040223, 
0.148183673176825, 0.197729400168618, 0.0143988726040223, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 0.026416829265647, 
0.133558046673528, 0.209180472082052, 0.236050809146251, 0.0976175536382913, 
0.0292512530065965, 0.101812500774896, 0.174260371593558, 0.219271020599832, 
0.463144839271102, 0.579809720448572, 0.533211794147367, 0.354756475417204, 
0.360085192050189, 0.632756755929504, 0.651577329569406, 0.413372358380034, 
0.39353139219339, 0.343985665201597, 0.0630375839987112, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 0.0486387113946889, 0.0434233717113424, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
0.0566884748189849, 0.147730165378273, 0.175734271938852, 0.0827651732357175, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
0.0385481628769098, 0.0378679011790819, 0.0463711724019298, 0.0200677200859207, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
4.44089209850063e-16, 4.44089209850063e-16, 0.0956901454944461, 
0.128909591738371, 0.141154302299272, 0.0459176646033779, 4.44089209850063e-16, 
0.0285709913087686, 0.251696828196291, 0.642847304447283, 0.731394702114536, 
0.603732256822183, 0.427997984883332, 0.635251048821539)
```

So, my questions are:  If both use MLE to estimate the parameters, then why are the results so different?  Then which fit is more reliable or which one do you recommend to use?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that your data hints at some multimodality and Matlab is using suboptimal starting values.

An empirical density plot of your data:

```
plot(density(x, bw = "SJ"))
```

[image: density plot]

First let's plot the R fit:

```
library(SpatialExtremes)
library(extRemes)
plot(fevd(x,threshold =0.15,type = 'GP',method = "MLE"))
```

[image: resulting plot]

The lower-left plot shows that we have achieved a decent fit. (Note that a different bandwidth than above is used for the kernel density estimate in this plot.)

Now we use your Matlab result as starting values:

```
fevd(x,threshold =0.15,type = 'GP',method = "MLE", 
     initial = list(shape = -1.0301, scale = 0.7534))
#fevd(x = x, threshold = 0.15, type = "GP", method = "MLE", 
#    initial = list(shape = -1.0301, scale = 0.7534))
#
#[1] "Estimation Method used: MLE"
#
#
# Negative Log-Likelihood Value:  -18.74149 
#
#
# Estimated parameters:
#     scale      shape 
# 0.6242056 -1.0736348 
#
# Standard Error Estimates:
#      scale       shape 
#0.000000020 0.001368606 
#
# Estimated parameter covariance matrix.
#              scale         shape
#scale  4.000000e-16 -2.598691e-17
#shape -2.598691e-17  1.873082e-06
#
# AIC = -33.48297 
#
# BIC = -30.5515 
#Warning messages:
#1: In log(z) : NaNs produced
#2: In log(z) : NaNs produced
plot(fevd(x,threshold =0.15,type = 'GP',method = "MLE", 
          initial = list(shape = -1.0301, scale = 0.7534)))
#Warning messages:
#1: In log(z) : NaNs produced
#2: In log(z) : NaNs produced
```

[image: second resulting plot]

We can clearly see that the fit is worse and we have a false convergence or local minimum issue. The warnings further reduce our confidence in this fit. I suggest that you try Matlab with different starting values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The R fit shows to be better than the one provided by Matlab, but this means that Matlab doesn't always provide a reliable fit?.When you say starting values you refer of using a different data set?

Comment: No, you use a numeric optimizer for fitting the distribution model. Numeric optimizers need values from where they can start the optimization. I'm referring to those. According to the documentation, `fevd` has a pretty sophisticated approach for finding good starting values.

Comment: Oh ok. So this means that the results from R are more reliable than the results from Matlab?

Comment: I don't like sweeping statements and I can't make statements about Matlab, but in this specific case the R fit is clearly better. However, I believe you could get a good fit from Matlab too if you supply decent starting values. In any case, it you are fitting a model you should always do appropriate diagnostics and never blindly trust a fit.